# elsarticle equal contribution and corresponding author (**, *)

Tags: elsarticle

I'm using the `elsarticle` documentclass and I want to define one of the authors to be both, corresponding and equal contributor. The result I want is that this author should have a double-asterisk and a single asterisk next to its name. I'm using the `cortext` command for both of these, as this should be the intended way to do it, but if I call it twice, the latter call will override the former.

How can I get both symbols next to the name of the author? Should I use a hack?

Minimum code to demonstrate the problem:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title}

\author[]{A. Adam\corref{contrib}\corref{corauthor}}
\author[]{B. Bedam\corref{contrib}}

\cortext[corauthor]{Corresponding author}
\cortext[contrib]{Authors contributed equally}

\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the elsarticle.cls.

original code:

```
\def\cormark[#1]{\edef\cnotenum{\Ref{#1}}\unskip%
   \textsuperscript{\sep\ifcase\cnotenum\or
   $\ast$\or$\ast\ast$\fi\hspace{-1pt}}\let\sep=,}**

\let\@cormark\@empty
\let\@cornotes\@empty
\newcounter{cnote}

\def\cortext[#1]#2{\g@addto@macro\@cornotes{%
    \refstepcounter{cnote}\elsLabel{#1}%
\def\thefootnote{\ifcase\thecnote\or$\ast$\or
  $\ast\ast$\fi}%
\footnotetext{#2}}}
```

Change the position of the coremark (the counter doesnt consider this since it is placed before the newcounter) \

```
\let\@cormark\@empty
\let\@cornotes\@empty
\newcounter{cnote}

\def\cormark[#1]{\edef\cnotenum{\Ref{#1}}\unskip%
   \textsuperscript{\sep\ifcase\cnotenum\or
   $\ast$\or$\ast\ast$\fi\hspace{-1pt}}\let\sep=,}**

\def\cortext[#1]#2{\g@addto@macro\@cornotes{%
    \refstepcounter{cnote}\elsLabel{#1}%
\def\thefootnote{\ifcase\thecnote\or$\ast$\or
  $\ast\ast$\fi}%
\footnotetext{#2}}}
```

equal contribution and corresponding author footnotes should be visible now